# Sidekiq looks for redis on localhost instead of remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, vagrant, docker, sidekiq

I have this in my sidekiq initializer:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']}/0", namespace: 'Tyresearch' }
end
```

When i boot sidekiq it starts fine on the correct host and port:

```
INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.2.4 with redis options {:url=>"redis://172.17.0.6:6379/0", :namespace=>"Tyresearch"}
```

However when I try to launch a worker or visit the sidekiq admin panel I get this error:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError at /sidekiq
Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

So, for some reason it now tries to connect on 127.0.0.1 instead of 172.17.0.6

Here is my env (the app is made of linked docker containers managed by vagrant)

```
{"ADMIN_EMAIL"=>"user@example.com",
 "ADMIN_NAME"=>"First User",
 "ADMIN_PASSWORD"=>"changeme",
 "BUNDLE_BIN_PATH"=>
  "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/bin/bundle",
 "BUNDLE_GEMFILE"=>"/var/www/Gemfile",
 "COLUMNS"=>"135",
 "GEM_HOME"=>"/var/bundle/ruby/2.1.0",
 "GEM_PATH"=>"",
 "GMAIL_PASSWORD"=>"Your_Password",
 "GMAIL_USERNAME"=>"Your_Username",
 "HOME"=>"/home/web",
 "HOSTNAME"=>"223b7ef7396f",
 "LESSCLOSE"=>"/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s",
 "LESSOPEN"=>"| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s",
 "LINES"=>"43",
 "LS_COLORS"=>
  "rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=
01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:
*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=0
1;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.
flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:
*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:",
 "NODE_PATH"=>"/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript",
 "PATH"=>
  "/var/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin",
 "POSTGRES_ENV_PASSWORD"=>"password",
 "POSTGRES_ENV_USERNAME"=>"postgres",
 "POSTGRES_ENV_VERSION"=>"9.3",
 "POSTGRES_NAME"=>"/tyresearch/postgres",
 "POSTGRES_PORT"=>"tcp://172.17.0.5:5432",
 "POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP"=>"tcp://172.17.0.5:5432",
 "POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR"=>"172.17.0.5",
 "POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT"=>"5432",
 "POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PROTO"=>"tcp",
 "PWD"=>"/var/www",
 "REDIS_NAME"=>"/tyresearch/redis",
 "REDIS_PORT"=>"tcp://172.17.0.6:6379",
 "REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP"=>"tcp://172.17.0.6:6379",
 "REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR"=>"172.17.0.6",
 "REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT"=>"6379",
 "REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO"=>"tcp",
 "ROLES"=>"[\"admin\", \"user\", \"VIP\"]",
 "RUBYLIB"=>
  "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib",
 "RUBYOPT"=>"-rbundler/setup",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION"=>"2.12",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN"=>"true",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_DEBIAN_FRONTEND"=>"noninteractive",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_DISPLAY"=>":20.0",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_LANG"=>"en_US.UTF-8",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_LANGUAGE"=>"en_US.UTF-8",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_SCREEN_DEPTH"=>"24",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_SCREEN_HEIGHT"=>"1020",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_SCREEN_WIDTH"=>"1360",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_SELENIUM_PORT"=>"4444",
 "SELENIUM_ENV_TZ"=>"\"US/Pacific\"",
 "SELENIUM_NAME"=>"/tyresearch/selenium",
 "SELENIUM_PORT"=>"tcp://172.17.0.7:4444",
 "SELENIUM_PORT_4444_TCP"=>"tcp://172.17.0.7:4444",
 "SELENIUM_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR"=>"172.17.0.7",
 "SELENIUM_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT"=>"4444",
 "SELENIUM_PORT_4444_TCP_PROTO"=>"tcp",
 "SELENIUM_PORT_5900_TCP"=>"tcp://172.17.0.7:5900",
 "SELENIUM_PORT_5900_TCP_ADDR"=>"172.17.0.7",
 "SELENIUM_PORT_5900_TCP_PORT"=>"5900",
 "SELENIUM_PORT_5900_TCP_PROTO"=>"tcp",
 "SHLVL"=>"1",
 "TERM"=>"xterm",
 "_"=>"/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/bundle",
 "_FIGARO_ADMIN_EMAIL"=>"user@example.com",
 "_FIGARO_ADMIN_NAME"=>"First User",
 "_FIGARO_ADMIN_PASSWORD"=>"changeme",
 "_FIGARO_GMAIL_PASSWORD"=>"Your_Password",
 "_FIGARO_GMAIL_PASSWORD"=>"Your_Password",
 "_FIGARO_GMAIL_USERNAME"=>"Your_Username",
 "_FIGARO_ROLES"=>"[\"admin\", \"user\", \"VIP\"]",
 "_ORIGINAL_GEM_PATH"=>""}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I missed to read the documentation carefully and didn't configure sidekiq clientside:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']}/0", namespace: 'Tyresearch' }
end
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']}/0", namespace: 'Tyresearch' }
end
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! I saw multiple posts with what I thought was the same line repeated until I looked more closely. Yours was the one that I realized that one is for server and the other for client.

Comment: what is `/0` at the end of url? in my sidekiq initializer it is `/12`.

Comment: @lvle /12 or /0 indicates the dataset, In redies there are 16 dataset from 0 to 15. please see this link `http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/09/24/storing-data-with-redis/`